# Get all TreeNodes that it is possible to make visible by scrolling

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Think of a TreeView that has got many nodes, so that not all of them are visible in the viewport. You have to scroll to see more of them.

I am looking for some property that gives me all the nodes that will be possible to show by just scrolling up/down i.e. All nodes that are not hidden inside a collapsed parent, no matter if they are seen in the viewport at the moment.

I know about IsVisible, which gives me the information whether or not a TreeNode is visible right now in the view. But that property will return false for nodes that I have to scroll to see.

Is there a suitable property or some other way to do this?

EDIT:
I am using Winforms

Comment: What UI framework are we talking about here? Is it web? wpf? winforms? silverlight? something else I forgot to mention?

Comment: It sounds like you want all the top level nodes as well as any child nodes where their parent is expanded. You should be able to code this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want all the top level nodes as well as any child nodes where their parent is expanded.

Here is a quick implementation using a recursive function:

```
public IEnumerable<TreeNode> GetVisibleNodes(TreeView view)
{
    List<TreeNode> nodes = new List<TreeNode>();
    foreach (TreeNode node in view.Nodes)
    {                
        nodes.AddRange(TraverseNode(node));
    }
    return nodes;
}

private IEnumerable<TreeNode> TraverseNode(TreeNode node)
{
    List<TreeNode> visibleNodes = new List<TreeNode>();
    visibleNodes.Add(node);
    if (node.IsExpanded)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode childNode in node.Nodes)
        {
            visibleNodes.AddRange(TraverseNode(childNode));
        }
    }
    return visibleNodes;
}
```

Usage:

```
var nodes = GetVisibleNodes(someTreeView);
```

Comment: Wow, I must have been really tired. Well...Anyhow, thanks for the code. It works fine, but I decided to make a shorter version with a globally allocated list for better performance (posted below). I have accepted your answer though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing. visibleNodes is declared outside the method for performance reasons. I call this method with the root node as argument.

```
    private void GetVisibleNodes(TreeNode node)
    {
        visibleNodes.Add(node);
        if (node.IsExpanded)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode childNode in node.Nodes)
            {
                GetVisibleNodes(childNode);
            }
        }
    }
```